What do we mean when we talk about Aristotelianism?
Let's say that "Aristotelianism" is a philosophical "view" based on Aristotle's thought. Let's say that the contents of this "view" are those presented in the Corpus Aristotelicum. There are different ways to systematize these contents. One way has been the "Latin" or "scholastic" Aristotle, typical of Thomas Aquinas or Averroes. Another way can be the one proposed following Trendelenburg, for example with Brentano. These systematizations encompasse a wide range of subjects, including logic, metaphysics, ethics, politics, science, and epistemology.
However, this way of viewing Aristotelianism is so broad that it encompasses many ways of understanding this "view". Is there any way to understand it more specifically and univocally?
Thanks in advance for your help.

The philosophical tradition inspired by the work of Aristotle. Aristotle's philosophy had an enormous influence on Greek, Arabic, Medieval (Europe) and Early Modern Eurepean philosophy.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Sure, but what are the constant features of this tradition? From this perspective, practically the entire history of philosophy, including Kant, Hegel, and Heidegger, has Aristotelian inspiration.

See e.g. Aristotelianism in the Renaissance.

@MauroALLEGRANZA "Inspiration" is a very subjective term, and it is difficult to define relatively objective characteristics in this regard.

Constant features? the works of Aristotle: Logic, Ethics, Metaphysics, Rethoric, Biology and (at least since Early Modern Europe) Physics.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Again, according to SEP: Aristotelianism = "the study of the writings attributed to Aristotle." From this perspective, almost any philosopher has been an Aristotelian.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Well, from that perspective, both Hegel and Brentano are Aristotelians because they read and comment on Aristotle's work (Logic, Ethics, Metaphysics...). But everyone knows that their philosophies are opposed.

What is the real problem? Like many other "isms", "Aristotelianism" is vague and there is no making it "univocal" because people will use words as they please. But if you want something more specific then just specify it accordingly. SEP offers a narrow option in the same paragraph, "strain of thought representing an exclusive commitment to Aristotelian notions and/or methods". Maybe relax "exclusive" to "prevalent". Or, since your tag is metaphysics, use "hylomorphism" instead. There is no squeezing Hegel and Brentano into that.

In same area Aristotelianism is still alive and well; see e.g. James Franklin, An Aristotelian Realist Philosophy of Mathematics: Mathematics as the Science of Quantity and Structure (Palgrave, 2014). Obviously, not in physics.

@Conifold Ok, so your answer to my question is simply "no", it's impossible to pinpoint a specific sense of what Aristotelianism is; it is a vague and ambiguous current. Not all "isms" are ambiguous, by the way. Catholicism is relatively straightforward to define according to a doctrine, a set of dogmas, assumptions, etc.
If I follow the most narrow option, then Aquinas is definitely not an Aristotelian, since his commintment to Aristotelian notions and methods is not strict. But sounds weird not seeing in Aquinas a kind of aristotelianism, doesn't it?

@MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, conventionally is alive. But is there any exact sense in which this convention is based?

@Conifold Furthermore, is it clear what exactly constitutes that set of notions that are strictly Aristotelian? If one stops believing that substance has hypokeimenon as a property but thinks of it differently, does that mean one ceases to be Aristotelian because of it?

Catholicism has a religious canon maintained by a hierarchical organization, this can hardly be expected in philosophy. And on philosophy even Catholicism is vague. Their preferred one is Thomism, but one can be a Molinist or even a Christian existentialist. Aquinas is surely a hylomorphist (albeit with the esse twist) and Aristotelian notions and methods are prevalent in his works. But you will always face these sorites dilemmas when dealing with concepts formed by family resemblance. Aristotle is vast, so two "Aristotelians" may share enough with Aristotle but little with each other.

Generally, as it has been pointed out, Aristotelianism encompasses all thought that features similar ideas.
The general thrust in which the term is mostly used is, in my experience, as a metaphysical/epistemological term opposed to Platonism, ie. Aristotelian is the view that true knowledge is about particulars that can be experienced and reasoned about (some form of Empiricism), not abstract ideals. The waters become muddy fast here, though, as both feature speculative elements that only much later, in British Empiricism onwards, started to be systematically reduced.
Thus, the idealistic Hegel is able to name himself Aristotelian albeit his metaphysical unity of Absolute Geist. That is because he takes sensual experience of particulars as a necessary starting point of true knowledge and insists that we can derive the true nature of being from that, while for Plato, the true ideas will always remain unreachable for us.

One could say that Socrates symbolizes the starting point of Western philosophy, although its roots go down to Pythagoras, Parmenidis and Heractlitus. In the same way we could say that Aristotelis symbolizes the ending (completion) (telos) of Clasical Greece. The past (old world) ideas have been infused into the new world (by the presocratics), revolutionized by Socrates, forged into the intelect by Plato and rationalized by Aristotelis. The outcome was the Hellenistic period. Philosophy - as we understand it today in out modern-western world - is in fact a by-product of the Aristotelian logic. But, his work, still contains all the links (although not always clearly understood) with the old world. He casts out the deamons of the past - either rationalizing them, or enclosing them in new (invented) words - and moves foreward preparing the stage for a new civilization; but the deamons are still there (obscured) and waiting to be revealed. Aristotelianism - for me - is exactly that; a "discussion" with logic, in the frontier of metaphysics.

Although I like your answer, because you try a coherent interpretation of Aristotle's philosophy (= systematic conclusion), the truth is that Aristotle is not simply logic, there is a metaphysical component as well and it is the substratum of the main categories that have been inherited in other thinkers (Thomas, Kant, Hegel, etc.).  Besides, you also do not say what characteristics define such a thought, leaving my question unresolved.
